# How to : Generic Binary Min Heap comparing members objects

Tags: c#, generics, mono, binary-tree

I'm creating a simple Binary min heap. It's clear to me how Binary heaps work and implementing them is not a problem. However I'm having trouble on how to implement a generic Binary heap ( a min heap in this case) considering that I want to store objects( rather than ints/floats/doubles/etc) in my tree that have members I want to compare in order to bubble the objects up or down.

Is there any solution to such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just need to constrain the generic type of T to be [`IComparable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx).

For example:

```
public sealed class BinaryMinHeap<T> where T: IComparable<T>
{
    ...
```

Then where you compare your elements of type T you do:

```
if (element.CompareTo(otherThing) > 0)
    ...
```

(Where the sign of the return value from CompareTo() tells you the order of the elements.)

The built-in types such as `int`, `double` and `string` all implement `IComparable<T>`, so this approach works with them too.

Alternatively, you could pass in a [`Comparison<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) delegate to be used when comparing the elements. Then the type T wouldn't have to implement `IComparable<T>`.

For an example of something that uses `Comparison<T>`, see [`Array.Sort<T>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxt053xf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: But how exactly am I comparing in the if statement? It's not clear to me how I can specify which member/property to compare.

Comment: @Sidar: how would you compare two `int`s? I would go for the latter solution (`Comparison<T>` or `IComparer<T>`), to avoid having to implement the interface (and it also allows you to sort using different properties each time).

Comment: Maybe i'm not getting it. Of course comparing ints is trivial. But in my case I have to specify a member/property. Which could be different with different objects I will store in my tree respectively.

Comment: If type T implements `IComparable<T>`, then anything of that type will have a `CompareTo()` method you can call, which you can use instead of the `>`, `<` and `==` operators. How much do you know about generics in C#? I think I've assumed you know more than you do...